# Copy data between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

The problem I have on hand is: I have an Excel file with multiple worksheets and it should populate cells in worksheet B with values from cells in worksheet A. I made a little macro for this but it just doesn't work like it should. Either go in totally different cells, throws and error or copies the formula and not the value.

The specifics are:

Data in Worksheet A is in the complete column H and starts in the second row. The data in these cells is a CONCATENATE from different fields.

The loop should take the first value from H2 in worksheet A and put it in worksheet B, B1. Then move onto H3 in worksheet A and put this value in worksheet B, C1 and so on.

It should do this till there is no value left in worksheet A column H.

```
     Sub Test2()

' Select the worksheet

Worksheets("A").Activate

' Select first cell with data

Range("H2").Select

' Loop until no data present

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

' Helper Variable for startpoint in worksheet B

Dim i As Integer
i = 8

     ' Copy first value
     Selection.Copy

     ' Go to different worksheet
     Worksheets("B").Activate

     ' Select first data entry point
     ActiveCell(1, i).Select

     ' Paste Data
     Selection.Paste

     ' Move helper variable in next column
     i = i + 1

     ' Return to worksheet A
     Worksheets("A").Activate

     ' Select next row
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

  Loop

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use this static code it works for the defined range

```
Sub Macro1()
Worksheets("A").Activate
Range("H2:H12").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("B").Activate
Range("B1:H13").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Seems somewhat more elegant as well but I don't know how to make it "flexible" as doing it till it comes to an empty cell.

The next problem I ran into is now in worksheet B it should do a matrix with this stuff. After the values are in row 1, column B and on I have this formula:

```
=Table2[[#Headers];[Column1]]
```

Now this formula should be extended to the numbers of the added data.

so something like

```
=Table2[[#Headers];[Column2]]
=Table2[[#Headers];[Column3]]
....
```

and so on depending on the numbers of added values.